# What is the violin technique in this video called?

Tags: technique, violin

At the very beginning that weird slide technique, what is it called? Is it a glissando. I want to call it a slide but I'm not sure. The soloist does it near the end as well.

It seems to be trying to mimic a person crying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like an ordinary gliss with the up bow, followed by a small gliss with the down bow, then sautille, which is similar to a fast, small spiccato.